# should i have to use error method in every callback function in express?

Tags: node.js, express

here is my code for my express application

```
app.listen(port, function(){console.log("Connected "+port);})
```

But when start server it shows error as `"Unhandled 'error' event" at event.js:163`
How to resolve it?
should i have to use error as parameter on every callback function?

Answer (score 2):

your server needs to handle `error` event. Use this instead

```
app.listen(port);
app.on('error', onError);
app.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Comment: I usually have process.on unhandledException handler also in this boilerplate

Comment: are you using `express-generator`